# Add Calendar event to Android from web .vcs download

Tags: android, calendar, icalendar

my current problem is the following; I am creating a website with two files for download(**.vcs** and .ics) that will add an event to the device calendar once clicked on the respective link. For the .ics in the iPhone I have no problem. My issue is that when downloading the **.vcs** file in Android it just opens a blank page showing the **.vcs** file content but is not downloading it neither recognizing the file as a calendar event.

I think as per what I read before in SO (and I was searching for that thread but could not find it now to reference) that has something to do with the **mime type** but after trying to figure out how to do it I cant make it work.

In that thread also they point to a site where the **vcs** file works for Android so is possible to do (I read many posts saying is not possible unless you download a calendar app from google play); http://plone.org/events/community/plone-conference-2011

I inspected that page source code and I am wondering if is something they are doing in the server side 
If you could please help me pointing out a direction to follow or a working solution or any advice you may have about it I will be thankfully.

PD - Is my first question in SO!

Comment: this is the SO post i finally found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700530/how-to-add-an-entry-in-the-android-calendar-from-an-html5-mobile-web-page . I tried adding http header <?
header("Content-type: text/x-vCalendar; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='london2012.vcs'");
?> but still does not works

Comment: did you solve this problem? could you please help me out with the same.

Comment: I solved it yes, the solution I used is in the answer, I dont know how you handle downloads in your app but is basically a link to a php file(an example in the answer).

Comment: Do we need to handle it separately for importing the csv file?

Comment: sorry but I dont understand what you mean, is just a link, where when you click goes to a php file that has the vcs specifying the header as in the solution.

Comment: I have a link with vcs file, when ever i click on that it get downloaded, and I need to import that vcs file in to my android calendar application programatically is that possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally got it working adding a link to a location with this index.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/x-vCalendar");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=london2012.vcs");
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//AT Content Types//AT Event//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20120801T133822Z
CREATED:20120801T042948Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20120801T043003Z
SUMMARY:Olympic Games
DTSTART:20120727T000000Z
DTEND:20120812T000000Z
LOCATION:London
URL:http://www.london2012.com/
CLASS:PUBLIC
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Then from Android it downloads the file and you can import it to the calendar.
Hope is usefull for someone else...

Comment: Hi, I want the same implementation in one of my application, do we need to handled the downloaded file in our application through program?

Comment: I copied above code and created one php file but after accessing vcs file get downloaded but it giving me same error "Can't Open file".

Comment: @Kammy try to copy only the first 4 lines, then put your real event calendar, i mean, this calendar is from 2 years ago, maybe has something to do with your error

Comment: @SantiagoRebella I tried it that too on my Kitkat 4.4.4 but it giving me same error. It it that android phone need other app to read ics/ical/vcs files as there is no default feature like iOS has?

Comment: @Kammy with this approach i didnt need any app in android to be imported into native calendar

Comment: Its working only for samsung smart phones. any solution for other providers (micromax,LG,Sony etc)