# href to "add to calendar" from web not working with native google calendar app on Android 6.0+

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-calendar-api, href, android-6.0-marshmallow

We have some href's linking to .ics files and google calendar etc. Everything works perfectly on the web and iOS devices. However, when linking to "Add to calendar" from Android 6.0+ within chrome, it auto opens the Google Calendar, which is expected, but then it just says "Event not found".

Our links are setup the same way as suggested answer in:
[Link to add to google calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10488831/link-to-add-to-google-calendar)

Doing some research there looks to be some issues with Android 6.0 and google calendar, but I'm wondering if on an Android 6.0+ device if anyone has found a workaround solution to get "Add to calendar" href link to add an event to the native google calendar app?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825221/add-calendar-event-to-android-from-web-vcs-download or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7700530/how-to-add-an-entry-in-the-android-calendar-from-an-html5-mobile-web-page

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no @BaronGrivet. All testing points to a bug within Android 6.0+

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else searching for a solution I ended up using: http://addtocalendar.com/

It's a free service and seems to use the browser interface for adding Calendar events on Android.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! ;)

Comment: addtocalendar uses the same href technique as the basic example linked in the original post, but with a slightly different base url that doesn't prompt mobile users to open in Google Calendar. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the addtocalendar library works is simply because it uses a different link structure that doesn't prompt mobile users to open in app: `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&...`. You can skip using that library and just swap in this base link structure.

There's a warning that pops up on the google calendar page this links to that things won't be rendered perfectly on mobile because it's the desktop view, but it works.