# "event not found" when trying to add event to google calendar with mark event button

Tags: wordpress, google-calendar-api

I created an event on Google calendar and I'm trying to embed a button that will mark this event for people on their calendar.
It's working fine on desktop but on mobile phones its alerting an error "Event not found".
My calendar is public on his sharing details, also the event is public, the code is this:

https://jsfiddle.net/4ch7n8xf/

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&amp;tmeid=OWd1dTBzdWpxamh2b3F1b2drOW1tbDUycDQgcDRpdjdwb2NkZmVoMW5wbmh2ZnJtNDhudThAZw&amp;tmsrc=p4iv7pocdfeh1npnhvfrm48nu8%40group.calendar.google.com"><img border="0" src="https://www.google.com/calendar/images/ext/gc_button1_en.gif"></a>
```

would really like some help please

Answer (score 2):

This is seems to be an issue with the Google Calendar app on Android 6.0, see [href to "add to calendar" from web not working with native google calendar app on Android 6.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853870/href-to-add-to-calendar-from-web-not-working-with-native-google-calendar-app-o).

My solution was to use an alternate link structure that doesn't prompt mobile users to open in app: `https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&...`. There's a warning that pops up on that page that things won't be rendered perfectly on mobile because it's the desktop view, but it works.